# Eigenvalues of Hamiltonian for a system w/ three interacting spin degrees of freedom with spin-1/2

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-spin, hamiltonian, eigenvalue

I have three interacting spin-1/2 particles and I want to find the energy eigenvalues of H.
The Hamiltonian for the system is
$ H = \frac{J}{\hbar^2}(S_1\cdot S_2+S_2\cdot S_3+S_3\cdot S_1)$ (where J is positive and has energy units)
and $S_{tot} = S_1+S_2+S_3$ and $S_{tot}^2 = S_{tot} \cdot S_{tot}$. 
I have expressed the Hamiltonian with $S_{tot}^2$ as

$H = \frac{J}{2\hbar^2}(S_{tot}^2-S_1^2-S_2^2-S_3^2)$
What I am struggeling with is using this new Hamiltonian on for example
$H|\uparrow \downarrow \downarrow \rangle$ and all other spin combinations. I managed to do so with the first expression for the Hamiltonian, but not with the new one.

And $S_1 = S\otimes I \otimes I$,
$S_2 = I \otimes S\otimes I$, 
$S_3 = I \otimes I\otimes S$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The energy eigenvalues are given by the spin quantum number as $S^2\mid\psi\rangle=s(s+1)\hbar^2\mid \psi\rangle$. For a system of three spins we have either $s_{tot}=\frac{3}{2}$ or $s_{tot}=\frac{1}{2}$, while $s=\pm\frac{1}{2}$. For a general three-spin system the energy eigenvalues of $H$ must be, for $s_{tot}=\frac{3}{2}, s=\frac{1}{2}$;

$\frac{J}{2\hbar^2}(S_{tot}^2-(S_1^2+S_2^2+S_3^2))\mid\psi\rangle =
\frac{J}{2\hbar^2}\left(\frac{3}{2}(\frac{3}{2}+1)\hbar^2 - 3\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}+1)\hbar^2\right)\mid\psi\rangle = J\frac{3}{4}\mid\psi\rangle$.

The rest should be relatively straight-forward. By the way, you had a small error in the second Hamiltonian expression.

Comment: So when $s=1/2$, the energy eigenvalues would be negative, therefore we can disregard those states?

Comment: $s_{tot} = 1/2$ I mean

Comment: Not at all. That an energy eigenvalue is negative does not mean it is wrong and can be disregarded. I think that this Hamiltonian is an interaction Hamiltonian and therefore only part of the full Hamiltonian. Negative energy is OK as long as there is more to the problem.

Comment: But $s_{tot}$ can be negative as well? $-3/2$ and $-1/2$?

Comment: Because when $s_{tot} =+/- 1/2$, will there be a change in the state, so there will not be an eigenstate then?

Comment: $s_{tot}$ can never be negative because its components, the spin angular momentum number $s_i$ is never negative. You may be mixing it up with the projection spin quantum number ($-s\leq m_s \leq s$).